# How to drop all graphs on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I want to drop all graphs on agensgraph with drop database.

Is there query finding all graphs?

```
agens=# SELECT GRAPHNAME FROM ?????;
 graphname 
-----------
 graph1
 graph2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AG_GRAPH table for finding all graphs.

And drop graph one by one.

```
agens=# SELECT GRAPHNAME FROM AG_GRAPH;
 graphname 
-----------
 graph1
 graph2
 graph
(3 rows)
agens=# DROP GRAPH GRAPH CASCADE;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 4 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to sequence graph.ag_label_seq
drop cascades to vlabel ag_vertex
drop cascades to elabel ag_edge
drop cascades to vlabel v
DROP GRAPH
agens=# DROP GRAPH GRAPH1 CASCADE;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 5 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to sequence graph1.ag_label_seq
drop cascades to vlabel ag_vertex
drop cascades to elabel ag_edge
drop cascades to vlabel v
drop cascades to elabel e
DROP GRAPH
agens=# DROP GRAPH GRAPH2 CASCADE;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 5 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to sequence graph2.ag_label_seq
drop cascades to vlabel ag_vertex
drop cascades to elabel ag_edge
drop cascades to vlabel v
drop cascades to elabel e
DROP GRAPH
```